# MinVar Portfolio Loop Optimization

Tags: r, optimization, portfolio, quantitative-finance

I am attempting to minimize the variance of a 3 stock portfolio using optimization within a loop.  What I have done is calculated the stock returns and cov matrix from dates 1980-01-01 to 1989-12-31 and optimized for the minvar portfolio using solve.QP. From here, I would like to calculate the minvar portfolio for every year leading up to date 2010-12-31 and store the weights and optimal value in a vector.  My code is as follows:

```
library(quantmod)
library(FRAPO)
library(quadprog)
getSymbols(c("F","AA","IBM"),from="1980-01-01",to="2010-12-31")
port=cbind(F$F.Adjusted,AA$AA.Adjusted,IBM$IBM.Adjusted)
portret=returnseries(port,"discrete",trim=TRUE)
portret=data.frame(date=index(portret),coredata=portret)
colnames(portret)=c("time","F","AA","IBM")
#to determine where to end portA
which(portret=="1989-12-29",arr.ind=TRUE)
#row number 2527 references date 1989-12-29
portA=subset(portret,select=c("F","AA","IBM"),subset=portret[,1]<portret[2527,1])
portAcov=cov(portA)
Dmat=portAcov
dvec=c(0,0,0)
A=c(1,1,1)
B=diag(3)
portAmeans=colMeans(portA)
Amat=cbind(A,portAmeans,B)
bvec=c(1,0,0,0,0)
sol=solve.QP(Dmat,dvec,Amat,bvec,meq=1)
#this gives me my minvar port weights for up to year 1990
portB=subset(portret,select=c("F","AA","IBM"),subset=portret[,1]>=portret[2527,1])
w=matrix(0,nrow(portB),3)
w[1,1:3]=sol$solution
v[1]=sol$value
v=matrix(0,nrow(portB),1)
for(i in (which(portret=="1990-01-02",arr.ind=TRUE)[1]:
          which(portret=="2010-12-31",arr.ind=TRUE)[1])){
Dmat=cov(subset(portret[,2:4],select=c("F","AA","IBM"),subset=portret[,1]
                                                       <portret[i,1]))
sol2=solve.QP(Dmat,dvec,Amat,bvec,meq=1)
for(j in 2:nrow(portB)){
w[j,1:3]=sol2$solution
v[j,]=sol2$value}}
```

For some reason my weight vector w and value vector v equal all the same numbers. I have been crunching this code for days and cant figure it out. Additionally, I want yearly values and weights (i.e. optimal minvar weights for year 1990, 1991, 1992... 2010 and the corresponding values). Is there a simple way to do this??

Comment: You override all of `w` at each iteration, instead of just one row:
what is left at the end is the last portfolio, everywhere.
(In addition, since you are estimating the covariance matrix 
on an expanding window, the weights may not change as much as you want.)

Comment: How is that possible?  When w and v are being populated the are being populated with loop variable j?

Comment: You have two nested loops: the weights are computed for each value of `i` (not `j`), and then written for all values of `j` (not `i`). If it is not clear, try to indent your code and/or add a print statement before the assignment, indicating which row is being written with what.

Comment: I actually just rewrote some of this code which answered one of my questions. I replaced j with i when populating the weight and value vectors while also making the necessary changes before the loop as well. This still leaves me with the fact that these are daily weights. I would like them annually